# How to find SharePoint instance in a domain?

Tags: tools

I wonder if there is a simple way to discover SP instances in a domain.

Maybe some scanners exist for this purpose. What's you advice? How to find installed SharePoint(doesn't matter what version) in a domain?

Comment: What is the objective of this?

Comment: I want to collect info about all SP farms of the customers I'm working with. To create a source containing system documentation which can be used by a support team.

Comment: SharePoint itself isn't leaky in that it wont advertise itself but you could try looking for specific SP Services running on services with System Center or similar tools.

Answer (score 3):

Hello and welcome to StackExchange.

You can scan for sharepoint instances using a free tool from McAfee:

http://www.mcafee.com/au/downloads/free-tools/sharepoint-discovery.aspx

Comment: Thank you, Rafał, but it doesn't work. I've run this tool as domain admin. It finds computers in domain, but I get "Unable to connect" message.

Comment: I haven't personally used this tool but I imagine it works somehow as a port scanner, so I guess maybe your machines block it?